# Google places API doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api, google-places

I am following [Google Places API for IOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) tutorial to view the user current place.

I used the same code in the tutorial as follow:

```
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

// Add a pair of UILabels in Interface Builder, and connect the outlets to these variables.
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
}

// Add a UIButton in Interface Builder, and connect the action to this function.
@IBAction func getCurrentPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {

placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    self.nameLabel.text = "No current place"
    self.addressLabel.text = ""

    if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
        let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
        if let place = place {
            self.nameLabel.text = place.name
            self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
                .joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }
})
}
```

But I get the following error in the console:

> Pick Place error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API
>   could not find the user's location. This may be because the user has
>   not allowed the application to access location information.

NOTE: I have set the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key (Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description) in `info.plist` file.

It's confusing because I followed the tutorial step by step. And am testing the application using physical device with "Locations Services" enabled .

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Or is it because the documentation is not up-to-date?

Comment: Have you prompted user for Location Usage Authorization?

Comment: @PGDev where should I put the code let locationManager = CLLocationManager(); locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization(); ? I tried inside viewDidLoad and nothing appeared, I tried inside the button when its pressed, it appears for less than a second and disappear without pressing anything.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Which device are you using to test your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This may be because the user has not allowed the application to access location information.

This points you towards your answer. For Google Places to work you need to request to use location services by calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. This will prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services.

Please refer to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization) for more info.

**EDIT**

You should keep a strong reference to the CLLocationManager that you create so it does not get deallocated when your function exits.

> "Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class and store a strong reference to it somewhere in your app.
>   Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete. Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient."

Taken from the [CLLocationManager Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

**EXAMPLE**

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate { 
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined
    {
       locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I put the code let locationManager = CLLocationManager(); locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization(); ? I tried inside viewDidLoad and nothing appeared, I tried inside the button when its pressed, it appears for less than a second and disappear without pressing anything.

Comment: You must store a strong reference to your location manager so it does not get deallocated when viewDidLoad exits. I have updated my answer

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Request user for **Location Usage Authorization**

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` OR `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` according to your requirement.

**2.** In `Info.plist`, add the following keys:

a. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` OR `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

b. `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`

**Example:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
    {

    }
}
```